# Problem with creating env with the help conda

Tags: anaconda, conda, python-bob

I try command: conda env create -f environment.yml

```
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Images are for when one requires showing something visually.

Comment: I use image because stackoverflow doesn't allow to write ```code``` a lot

Comment: You don't need to write code but just paste the error message into the question. What you did above is useless.